# How to make user profile link like facebook for my web page

Tags: php, url, yii

I am developing a web page using Yii framework, I want to do url management like facebook.
This is my url **www.mywebpage.com/user/profile/id/10** but i dont want to show this url like this, i would like to show like this **www.mywebpage.com/yogi** can i do it in Yii? please anyone help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this article out to get started:
http://yiitutorials.net/easy/easy-url-rewriting-with-yii

You will bascially be storing the users custom URL in the database. So an example URL would be http://example.com/user/userurl

In your main config you could set up a rule like:

```
user/<customurl:.+> => 'user/view' //second part is the controller/action
```

That rule defines that a URL with 'http://example.com/user/', the part after the slash can be accessed by a GET variable with the name 'customurl'. You can then access the users custom URL like so:

```
$_GET['customurl'];
```

And query the user record something like so:

```
$user = User::model()->find("customurl = '".$_GET['customurl']."'");
```

As mentioned below, [here is an example from a real website](http://poplondon.co.uk/london-blog/renting-a-property-in-london/8). In this example the URL looks like so: http://website.com/blog/{post_title}/{post_id}

So the rule for this would be something like:

```
london-blog/<post_title:.+>/<post_url:.+> => 'blog/viewpost'
```

So in our blog controller, we have an action called viewpost (see above how the rule is pointing to this controller/action?), which would look something like:

```
public function actionViewpost(){
    $blogpost = Blog::model()->find("post_title = '".$_GET['post_title']."'");
    ...
}
```

So any URL that has the format london-blog/some_value/some_value will point to the controller action as specified in the config. You can then access the some_value parts using the variable names defined in the config (the bits in the < :.+>)

Hope that helps!

Comment: can you explain more clear please

Comment: what do you not understand? Start by reading the article I posted a link to, it will give you a good basic understanding of how the URL rewriting works in Yii

Comment: how do i do it dynamically for all users? i have a 10000 of user what changes can i made in config file? if i done like this ('yogi'=>'user/profile/id/44') its work for only one user how can i do it for all 10000 of users?

Comment: How do i specify the the name and id in config file dynamically? if user hit a url like www.somewebpage.com/jhon how do i get the id and name jhon('?'=>'user/profile/id/?').

Comment: Yes i got it ('<customurl:.+>'=>'user/stream/id/14'). now i can get name by $_GET['customurl'] coustomurl nothing but username. but how can i get the id of username from database in config file?

Comment: The rule in your config is dynamic, as in the "customurl" part of user/<customurl:.+> => 'user/view' is saying that a url that looks like http://yourwebsite/user/whatever is pointing to the controller/action specified there (user/view in my example), and you can access the second part of the URL (the part that says "whatever" in this example) as a $_GET variable called customurl. I will update my example with a reference to a real website that uses this

Comment: I asked a new question please check the [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13120654/how-to-create-custom-url-in-yii)

Comment: I completely understand your question, you don't need to repost it. Specifically what are you not understanding? Have you read the blog post link? Maybe edit your question with some sample code from your application

Comment: Thank you so much eskimo! I done it. sorry for ask you lot of questions :)

Comment: No problem saas, hope you come right!

Answer (score 0):

I think all the information that you need is here: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.url

Comment: yes thanks a lot, i saw that too it show static content like sit/home mean its shows home, but how do i do it dynamically with user name?