# How to create custom url in Yii

Tags: php, yii, url-mapping

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to make user profile link like facebook for my web page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13117488/how-to-make-user-profile-link-like-facebook-for-my-web-page)

How do i manage custom url for user profile like

```
www.exampl.com/brito  insted of  www.exampl.com/user/profile/id/22
www.exampl.com/jhon   insted of  www.exampl.com/user/profile/id/31
www.exampl.com/piter  insted of  www.exampl.com/user/profile/id/66
```

I have done below code in my config/main.php file, now its works for this 3 static users only. how can i change it dynamically for all 1000 of users?

```
  urlManager'=>array(
                'urlFormat'=>'path',
                'showScriptName'=>false,
                'rules'=>array(
                    '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
                    '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
                    '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
                    'brito'=>'user/profile/id/22',
                    'john'=>'user/profile/id/31',
                    'piter'=>'user/profile/id/66',
                ),
            ),
```

Please help me any one.

Comment: first, check what the yii community has to offer; i am sure that you will find there a url friendly extension/addon/module

Answer (score 0):

use htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# If the request is for a valid directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
# If the request is for a valid file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
# If the request is for a valid link
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l
# do not do anything
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# forward /blog/foo to blog.php/foo
RewriteRule ^blog/(.+)$ blog.php/$1 [L,NC]

# forward /john to user/profile/?name=john
RewriteRule ^((?!blog/).+)$ user/profile/?name=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

and make sure u must include the `name` in the page

Comment: i dont want send name in query string, i want to send user id in query string how do i it? john id is 31 so how do i get 31 in htaccess or config/main.php dynamically?

Comment: that's not possible i think, u can't perform database operations in htaccess file, and i dont think u can write rule like this in main.php config too..

Comment: Yes thanks a lot! I done it by other way but your answer was useful for me.

Comment: glad to know that, and can u share the method u used